# Can I get a crew transfer milestone with the EVA jetpack?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

The *transfer crew* objective has this description:

> Transfer any crew into any vessel from another mission in orbit of *<body>* to achieve this goal.

One thing this doesn't make clear is, do I really need to dock for this? Docking is of course the easiest method, but I could also, say, go EVA and jetpack between vessels. There are a few reasons why I might want to do this:

- If I don't have the technology for docking
- If I have a rescue target near the same body
- If I aborted a landing but have the fuel and space for a rendezvous maneuver before returning

So would this count?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, you can! That's usually how I get the transfer milestones. One thing to consider: Depending on how it checks for the transfer, the rescue target combination might not work.

Comment: I suspect EVA may actually be *mandatory*: due to the internals of how KSP works, two docked vessels are treated as a single vessel.

Comment: I think you're right.

Comment: @Mark I know I've gotten it with docking; it likely considers the individual pods, not the ship as a whole.